Cannot Click find & click button in LinkedIn automation : Python-Selenium
I've been trying to build a little python-Selenium script to help me automate my linkedIn networking. I want my script to go through my pre defined search criteria and send each result a connection request. I will be adhering to the fair usage as no one likes abuse of these things bUt who has time to spend all day on linkedIn when you can automate this! I'm a pretty casual programmer these days and happy with what i have so far as i'm new to Python-Selenium. I have the script opening linkedin, logging in and finding the profiles that match my criteria. The issue I have is that I cant seem to get Selenium to find or click the 'connect' button. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here or do i have it right but Linkedin Bot checks are just too good for this type of thing and i should just not waste the time?
Thanks in advance.
# Iterate through each profile link and perform actions
for link in profile_links:
    if profiles_processed >= rate_limit:
        print(f"Rate limit of {rate_limit} profiles reached. Stopping the script.")
        break

    try:
        # Open the profile in a new tab
        profile_url = link.get_attribute("href")
        driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0], '_blank');", profile_url)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])  # Switch to the new tab
        time.sleep(3)

        # Step 1: Try to find and click the 'Connect' button based on the Linkedin 'connect button' HTML 
        try:
            connect_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label, 'Invite') and contains(@class, 'artdeco-button--primary')]"))
            )
            connect_button.click()
            print("Clicked 'Connect' on the profile page.")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Couldn't find 'Connect' button on the profile page, skipping this profile.")
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch back to the original tab
            continue

        # Step 2: Handle the modal (wait for it to appear and click 'Send without a note')
        try:
            send_without_note_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@aria-label, 'Send without a note')]"))
            )
            send_without_note_button.click()
            print("Connection request sent without a note.")
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Failed to send the connection request due to modal issue.")

        # After connecting or failing, close the tab and switch back to the search results tab
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch back to the original tab

        profiles_processed += 1

        # Randomized wait before moving to the next profile
        time.sleep(random.randint(10, 20))  # Random delay between 10 to 20 seconds

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}. Skipping this profile.")
        driver.close()  # Close the tab if there was an error
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch back to the original tab
        continue


This kind of thing is expressly forbidden by LinkedIn's terms of use

In general as you said: Linkedin Bot checks are just too good for this. But let's give it a shot.
But in order to assist, you have to define all type of buttons can be clicked. What buttons are shown changes for every visit. In this exact case there is also an option for follow instead of connect (artdeco-button--secondary), and the connect button doesn't always show. Sometimes you have to click the more.. button.
It can be kind of a rabbit hole though. As a general rule of thumb, if you can pay for the API access, you can be sure someone has deviced a way to prevent or reduce bot traffic. But you can always try!
